# BestBuy rejecting curl from ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ec2

Hm so heres the case, I want to be notified when something appears on bestbuy.com. Curl user-agent must have been blacklisted because setting a custom one gives me a response.

```
curl --user-agent 'do-it-to-it' --compressed https://www.bestbuy.com
```

However I want to run command this on a VM. The command above **works on my local machine** but when executed on a VM it returns `Access Denied`.

The file on LEFT is from EC2, the file on RIGHT is from local machine. You can see that I get a HTTP 403 from the EC2. I just don't understand what the server is catching that is causing it to reject the request from my EC2, the main difference I see here is the certificate `ca-bundle.crt` vs `cert.pem`.

[image: file diff]

Comment: You appear to be running curl with `--verbose`, this includes all headers sent.  Often many modern websites use heuristics to determine if you're allowed access, and those heuristics often give AWS IP addresses a large negative score.  You can try making curl look more like a real browser, notably with a real User Agent, it might help.  Depends on the site.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely the range of Public IP addresses assigned to Amazon EC2, which is public knowledge.

Many websites do not want people scraping their site and since a lot of web scraping is done from virtual machines, they choose to block access from Amazon EC2 instances.

You should use the [BestBuy API](https://developer.bestbuy.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the response John. The bestbuy API doesn't allow free or .edu emails unfortunately, I'll explore if it's worth paying for an email in order to use it. But your comment about the Public IP addresses was helpful and informative.